# Is the infimum of a set of positive numbers also positive?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a>0$. Consider the set $S=\{a, a, a, \dots\}$. Would it be valid to conclude that $\inf S >0$? Or can we just say that $\inf S \ge0$? Can someone please also provide a proof for whichever side they are on?

Comment: That specific $S$ can be shorter written as $S = \{a\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So, $\inf S = a>0$? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Generally, however, the infimum of a set of strictly positive numbers can be $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer How can that be?  Isn’t the infimum the minimum value?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Yes, I think that's what's going on. $S$ has a maximum, a minimum, a least upper bound, and a greatest lower bound. But, due to how $S$ is defined, the maximum, minimum, least upper bound, and the greatest lower bound of $S$ are all the same value: $a$.

Comment: But $a$ is positive so the infimum has to be positive, because the infimum is $a$.  Right?

Comment: @DanielFischer If all the numbers are positive, then the infimum can’t be zero because all of the numbers are greater than zero.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw The infimum need not belong to the set. If you look at the set of all strictly positive real numbers, or the set $\{2^{-n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, the infimum is $0$ because no strictly positive number is a lower bound.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh I see.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infimum is also known as the greatest lower bound, which helps us answer your question.

If we have $S=\{a,a,a,a,a,...\}$, then there are duplicates of $a$. As Daniel Fischer has pointed out, when dealing with sets, we ignore duplicates. Therefore, the set can be written more concisely as

$$
S=\{a\}
$$

In this particular case, the greatest lower bound is synonymous with the minimum. The minimum of $S$ is $a$, and so the greatest lower bound is $a$. The greatest lower bound is only an interesting concept when deal with something such as

$$
S=\mathbb{R^+}
$$

Here, there is no minimum. For any member of $S$, $m$, $\frac{m}{2}$ is smaller. However, the greatest lower bound of $S$ is $0$. We know that no member of $S$ is smaller than $0$, and that $0$ is the *greatest* number with this property. Equivalently, $0$ is the largest number where every member of the set $S$ is greater than or equal to it. If instead we picked a number such as $0.01$ as our greatest lower bound, then this would be incorrect as $0.005$ is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, we have $S=\{a\}$, and hence $\inf S=a$.

But more generally, if $S$ is a set of strictly positive real numbers, its infimum can still be equal to $0$. An example would be $S=\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\dots\right\}=\left\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\right\}$.